# how to succeed to match <? in javascript in lampp with str.match

Tags: javascript, regex, lampp

I have a conflict to match a < in javascipt with the function match().
Notice that the same line code works in wamp but not in lampp(linux).

```
with test, I notifie that the problem comes  from <? :
there's a warning 'parse error unexpected ')' in ....... '
but there will not be warning if I remove < or ? or <?.
```

here's the code:

```
var res=str.match(/[^<>]*<\w+ nom?="([^<>]*)">[^<>]*(<?[\s\S]*)/);
```

So, how can I fix this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a workaround by replacing `?` with the long version `{0,1}`.

```
var res=str.match(/[^<>]*<\w+ nom?="([^<>]*)">[^<>]*(<{0,1}[\s\S]*)/);
```

`?` is just a shortcut for the quantifier `{0,1}` meaning exactly the same.